# use mutate to create column of lengths of string from previous column r

Tags: r, string, dplyr

When I run the following program, I do not get the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)

dfr <- data.frame(sym = c("aa","bbb","c","dd"))

dfr %>% mutate( len = length(sym) )
```

The output is (`mutate` is clearly treating "sym" as the entire column instead of single entry)

```
  sym len
1  aa   4
2 bbb   4
3   c   4
4  dd   4
```

I want the output to be (note I *must* use `mutate`)

```
  sym len
1  aa   2
2 bbb   3
3   c   1
4  dd   2
```

Comment: Alternatively to `stringr::str_count` we can use base R `nchar` to count the number of characters in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `stringr::str_count()` to count the number of characters.

```
library(stringr)
libaray(dplyr)

dfr %>% mutate(len = str_count(sym))

  sym len
1  aa   2
2 bbb   3
3   c   1
4  dd   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `nchar(sym)` instead of `length(sym)` should get what you want.